# How to give some padding the cells which cells are being not edited in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid. It's first row is editable. Later on, every row at the bottom is also editable if double-clicked. But by default first row is editable and focused. Later rows are there. But I want some padding for the rows at the bottom which **are not being edited.**

Answer (score 0):

You should create a specif class for handling that padding in the bottom rows. If you have problems overwriting the jqGrid css add the !important atribut. For example:

```
.row-not-edited{ 
  padding: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Where to add it? Please Clarify. I am pretty new in this.

Comment: Ok. I understand that I have to add this to the CSS file. But then what needs to be done? please help.

Comment: Nothing, you should be able to see the change when you refresh your page.  You should use a browser like Firefox with Firebug or Chrome so you can make these changes dynamically to the page without having to reload and then you can see instantly what your changes do to the output.

Comment: I have added the code `.row-not-edited{ 
  padding: 10px !important;
}`

But I don't see any changes. Should I make change to anything else?

Comment: You should call this class to all your rows not edited. (<tr class="row-not-edited">bla bla</tr>).

Comment: How can I call the tr? they are being created automatically. So?